# An open connected subset of a Peano space is arcwise connected.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, proof-writing, proof-explanation, connectedness

prove : An open connected subset of a Peano space is arcwise connected.

**Def: A Peano space is a compact, connected, locally connected metric space.**

Proof (not my proof):-

I'll use the definition of a Peano as a locally connected, connected, compact metric space.\

A standard fact is that such spaces are also locally path-connected.\
Let $A$ be any open connected subset of a Peano space.\

Being open implies it's also locally connected and locally path-connected.\

Being connected we use the theorem that a locally path-connected connected set is path-connected,

and then apply the fact due to Sierpinski that a Hausdorff path-connected space is arcwise connected.\

Therefore, $A$  is arcwise connected.

> Why these are true ??

1) A standard fact is that such spaces are also locally path-connected.

2) being open implies it's also locally connected and locally path-connected.

Thanks

Comment: $A$ is $not$ compact unless $A=X$ or $A=\phi$ because if $A$ is compact it is closed (because $X$ is Hausdorff) but $A$ is assumed to be open, and $X$ is connected. Also, $h^{-1}$ and $h^{-1}|_A$ may fail to be functions.

Comment: thanks,see my new update

Comment: Whether $A$ ( or any space) is or is not homeomorphic to $I$ does not tell you whether $A$ is connected.  An open ball in $\Bbb R^2$ is connected but not homeomorphic to $I$..... BTW you deleted the reference to a theorem in the text, which I think should be restored.

Comment: thanks a lot,see my new update

Comment: This might help: See Q # 39584 : Reference for a proof of Hahn-Mazurkiewicz Theorem.  This is not a topic that I am familiar with,